# Android: How to pass a Bluetooth connection to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, netbeans, bluetooth

I have my first Activity in which the BT connection is established. There is an option presented to the user and, based on their selection, a different Activity will load.

The problem is, both activities need a BT connection and I don't see the point in destroying one connection just to make another.

Is there a way that I could pass the connection between Activities?

Does anyone have some example for me or perhaps a link?

I've tried "`class MyApplication extends Application`", but then I can't use:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.blablabla);
```

This may be a pretty silly question but I've only been at Android +- 2 weeks.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Keeping a Bluetooth connection across activities on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3132532/816008)

Comment: This link shows great explanation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112573/keeping-threads-and-connection-state-in-android-app-using-onsaveinstancestate

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the Application object to store the Bluetooth connection in an object and using your Activities to get it?

Try something like this. (Note: I have never worked with Bluetooth on Android, so I don't know which relevant classes to use. In this case, I'll use `BluetoothDevice`, since it seems to be the right class based on the library documentation)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    BluetoothDevice device;
    ...
    public synchronized BluetoothDevice getBtConnection() {
        if (device == null) {
            // construct a BluetoothDevice object and put it into variable device
        }
        return device;
    }
}
```

That way, your first activity just has to do this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super(b);
        ...
        device = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getBtDevice();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then, any time your other Activities need to use that connection, they just need to call `getBtDevice()`, because `FirstActivity` already instantiated it.

Comment: Hmm, I've not tried this yet. I'm really new to Android so I'll do my best and see if it works(hopefully it does).

Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Bundle?

Check relevant topic

http://www.anddev.org/putting_an_object_into_a_bundle-t6431.html

Comment: What do you mean? How would I use it? Pretty new to this :)

Comment: You push data in your intent and pass that intent to the next activity. In that activity you can ask for that data with Bundle.getExtras("key");

Comment: It seems that I can only pass primitive. I need to pass an object.

Comment: It still wont work :( The app crashes and hangs my phone :O
I did it exactly the same way as  was done in the two examples. It works with normal class objects, but not a bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for the new people visiting this topic:

I think Kibibyte's answer would also work, but otherwise there is the option to use a `(Bound)Service`. This would run even if the app closes

[Official Android Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

Answer (score -1):

i had same problem ,and finally solve it!
so at first you should create your connection in an activity and be sure that the connection store in ***public static*** variable and you can call that connection variable in each activity that you want to have Bluetooth Connection.
I suggest you to use service class to create connection and use connection variable like this

```
BluetoothChatService mChatService=DeviceListActivity.chatService
```